# image onLoad function on IPAD javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad

Hello
I am trying to write a simple javascript function that zooms images with javascript and using this on Ipad. But it seems that, when the new zoomed size is more that 2000px Ipad doesn't fire the onload event of the image tag. Here is my code:

```
img2 = new Image(sImg.outerWidth()*zoomSize,sImg.outerHeight()*zoomSize);
img2.src = sImg.attr('href');
img2.onload=function () {
        alert('zoom done');
};
```

onload event is not fired when sImg.outerWidth()*zoomSize>2000? Is this a ipad safari bug?

Comment: i have the same problem. i temporany resolved setting the size image after loading image, onload function. It seems to be a bug of safari, even of pc it gives this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    img2 = new Image(); 
img2.src = sImg.attr('href'); img2.onload=function () {
            sImg.outerWidth()*zoomSize,sImg.outerHeight()*zoomSize
            alert('zoom done'); };
```